# Как заменить строки местами в файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, замена

Есть некоторый массив данных с координатами различных атомов.

Необходимо написать скрипт, чтоб переместить 7 строк из середины файла таким образом, чтоб они стали на места со 2-рой строки по 8-ю, сдвинув все остальные вперёд.

Как это сделать в Python?

Comment: Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V.

Comment: Прочитать. Переместить (см. выше). Записать.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
In [360]: n=7; m=5

In [361]: l = list(range(20))

In [362]: l
Out[362]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

In [363]: l[:] = l[:1] + l[m:m+n] + [x for i,x in enumerate(l[1:]) if not m <= i <= m+n]

In [364]: l
Out[364]: [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать срезы 
 `arr = arr[:1] + то что нужно вставить + arr[7:]` 
при этом удалить то что берете для вставки